# How to switch to sub tools in photoshop using keyboard? Move tool to Artboard tool

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

Artboard tool is under move tool, but keyboard shortcut for both move tool as well as artboard tool is "v" (as stated on adobe website).

But when I press "v" on the keyboard it selects move tool.
How can select Artboard tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> while pressing the tool shortcut cycles through alternate tools in the default shortcut settings.

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks so much. 
Shift + Tool shortcut.

Comment: It's actually left clicking the tool + alt. 2020 version.